# Unpermitted attributes _destroy when deleting nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following railscasts#196 but using Rails 4 - I'm running into a problem when attempting to delete an answer from a question parent model.

**Unpermitted parameters: _destroy**

_answer_fields.html.erb

```
<fieldset>                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    <%= f.text_field :response %>                                                                                                                                                                       
    <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    <%= link_to "remove" , "#", class: "remove_fields" %>                                                                                                                                               
</fieldset>
```

question.rb

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :allow_destroy => true
```

surveys_controller.rb

```
def survey_params                                                                                                                                                                                       
  params.require(:survey).permit(:name, :questions_attributes => [:id, :content, :answers_attributes => [:id, :response]])                                                                              
end
```

I'm removing the fields from the form on click fine but the record has not been deleted.

Thanks

**Edit:** JS to set the hidden variable

```
 jQuery ->                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        $(document).on 'click' , ".remove_fields" , (event) ->                                                                                                                                              
                $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')                                                                                                                                                 
                $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()                                                                                                                                                          
                event.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Hitham S. AlQadheeb may be right – check that your models are correct...

*survey.rb*

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end
```

and *question.rb*

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

the `Unpermitted parameters: _destroy` error however should actually be referring to your controller's implementation of Strong Params: `survey_params`. You need to tell rails that your form will be passing the `:_destroy` field. Try this:

```
def survey_params                                                                                                                                                                                       
  params.require(:survey).permit(:name, :questions_attributes => [:id, :content, :_destroy, :answers_attributes => [:id, :response, :_destroy]])                                                                              
end
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've made those changes and I think it's closer now a I'm not getting any warnings/errors. I'm seeing the _destroy attribute is always set to false though - so each db call i s an update, added my JS above if you have a suggestion.

Comment: actually disregard - got it working now thanks a lot and @Hitham S. AlQadheeb

Answer (score 1):

It should be

*question.rb*

```
belongs_to :survey 
has_many :answers, : dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :allow_destroy => true
```

Look at it again http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1